# Умножение значения слайдера на число jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, rangeslider

Отдам все свои драгоценные благодарности в руки тому, кто сможет помочь молодому дизайнеру  понять `jQuery`.

Есть [слайдер](https://github.com/supertorio/angular-rangeslider-directive) (на Ангуларе), в диапозоне от 1 до 5 (кв.м) он выдает значения с шагом в `0.1`.
С целью получения клиентом цены за количество квадратных метров на сайте, очень сильно хочу умножать цену `12 000 ₽` за кв.м.
Мой итог – ручка слайдера двигается, но прописанные `12 000 ₽` не меняются.

Сам скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function update() {
        var bill_slider = $('.ng-binding');
        var yearly_bill = (bill_slider * 12000);
        $("#duration").text(yearly_bill);
    }
});
```

Вовлеченные персонажи:

```
<div class="bubble value low" id="amount" style="left: -12px;">
<b class="ng-binding">1</b> м²
</div>

<span style="font:800 233.3% 'Proxima';" id="duration">12 000</span> ₽
```

Comment: Ну и зачем с ангулярным слайдером использовать jQuery? Используй ангуляр...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, для конкретно своего случая со слайдером, состоящим из div блоков, выработал вариант на основе предложенного.

Суть здесь в том, что функцию активирует событие mousemove (touchmove для тачскринов) на участке слайдера. А лучше даже кинуть его на весь div/section–блок, в котором лежит слайдер, чтобы вычисление не затупило, когда ваш курсор доходит до крайнего значения слайдера и выходит за его предел. В моем случае это блок с классом counter.

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".counter").on('mousemove touchmove', function(){
        var bill_slider =   $('b.ng-binding').text();
        var yearly_bill = (parseFloat(bill_slider) * 12000);
        $("#duration").text(parseInt(first_type));
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<section class="counter">
  <div class="bubble value low" id="amount" style="left: -12px;">
      <b class="ng-binding">1</b> м²
  </div>
  <span style="font:800 233.3% 'Proxima';" id="duration">12 000</span> ₽
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".slider").on("input", function(){ 
        $('b.ng-binding').text($(this).val())
        var bill_slider =   $('b.ng-binding').text();
        var yearly_bill = (parseInt(bill_slider) * 12000);
        $("#duration").text(yearly_bill);
    });
});
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;    
    width: 70%;
    height: 25px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slidecontainer"> 
  <p>Сколько м² в квартире вы хотите?</p>
  <span>1 м²</span><input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange"><span>100 м²</span>
</div>

<div class="bubble value low" id="amount" style="left: -12px;">
<br/>
Желаемая площадь квартиры: <b class="ng-binding">1</b> м²
</div>

<p>Стоимость квартиры:<br/><span style="font:800 233.3% 'Proxima';" id="duration">12 000</span> ₽</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: написано все так толково, и с юай–слайдером работает замечательно, и так обидно, что у меня и сейчас эти 12 000 вообще неподвижные... но учитывая, что у меня нет импутов в слайдере (там все на дивах), не совсем понял, что происходит на строке `$(".slider").on("input", function(){`

Comment: @Payjay https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: @Payjay  Событие [input](https://learn.javascript.ru/events-change#%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-input) срабатывает тут же при изменении значения текстового элемента и поддерживается всеми браузерами.

Comment: @Payjay По какому действию вам нужно изменять значения?

Comment: про input понял, спасибо. по сути, получается, по факту изменения значения в слайдере, т.е. в b.ng-binding. просто я не знаю, за что еще там можно зацепиться. грубо говоря, он постоянно должен умножать значение слайдера на эти проклятые 12 000 в спане. надеюсь, объяснил не совсем, как аутист

Comment: @Payjay "он постоянно должен умножать значение слайдера" - Ваша задача запустить скрипт при каком либо действии. Скрипт должен вытащить числовое значение с .ng-binding , умножить его на 12000 и вывести результат.  Соответственно "ng-binding" должен обновляться на нужное вам значение иначе результат всегда будет 12000.     result = 1*12000;

Comment: так и подумал позже. хорошо, могу ли я вызывать скрипт по передвижению, клику бегунка слайдера? или даже вмомент перетаскивания его мышью, потому как бегунком является отдельный div, и я лишь полагаю, но чем-то это может помочь?

Comment: @Payjay Можно вызвать как угодно, если бы был весь ваш код(слайдер) или хотя бы что то приближенное, можно было бы сделать наглядно по вашему пример.

Comment: https://github.com/supertorio/angular-rangeslider-directive только так могу, в фиддле совсем не инициализируется

Comment: @Payjay вообще по идеи нужно делать без Jquery :) Может есть документация,  погуглите. Может поможет:  [angularjs-slider](http://angular-slider.github.io/angularjs-slider/),  [Angular Rangeslider Directive Example](https://codepen.io/neysimoes/pen/obMEmv)